# updating the score properly using Hooks (Rock paper scissor game made with React and Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a simple counter while practicing Hooks:

```
function App() {
  const cpuWeapon = ["paper", "rock", "scissor"];
  const [playerChoice, setPlayerChoice] = useState({
    playerOne: {
      choice: "",
      score: 0
    },
    playerTwo: {
      choice: "",
      score: 0
    }
  });

  const { playerOne, playerTwo } = playerChoice;

  const selectWeapon = weapon => {
    const player1 = weapon;
    const player2 = cpuWeapon[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

    setPlayerChoice({
      playerOne: {
        choice: player1,
        score: getScore(player1, player2)
      },

      playerTwo: {
        choice: player2,
        score: getScore(player1, player2)
      }
    });
  };

  const getScore = (pl1, pl2) => {
    if (pl1 === "paper") {
      if (pl2 === "scissor") {
        return playerTwo.score + 1;
      } else if (pl2 === "rock") {
        return playerOne.score + 1;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

The problem here is that **I'm getting the same update for both scores when the component render**, even if I specify in the return the different objects.

How can I overcome this?
Which is the best approach in those situations with react?

Comment: What value you are passing to selectWeapon( ) function?

Answer (score 1):

No wonder you the get same update for both scores, as you are setting the same value: `getScore(player1, player2)`

I suggest you replace your `getScore` function with:

```
const getWinner = (pl1, pl2) => {
  // Compare pl1 and pl2 and return:
  // * 0 in case of tie,
  // * 1 if player one wins,
  // * 2 if player two wins
};
```

Then, in your `selectWeapon` function, add:

```
...
const winner = getWinner(player1, player2);
setPlayerChoice({
  playerOne: {
    choice: player1,
    score: playerOne.score + (winner === 1 ? 1 : 0)
  },
  playerTwo: {
    choice: player2,
    score: playerTwo.score + (winner === 2 ? 1 : 0)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but now the result is showing correctly but is resetting every time.

Comment: @ChirstianaEriksten please check my update (there were missing parentheses)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this

```
function App() {
const cpuWeapon = ["paper", "rock", "scissor"];
const [playerOne,setPlayerOne]=useState(0)
const [playerTwo,setPlayerTwo]=useState(0)
const { playerOne, playerTwo } = playerChoice;

const selectWeapon = weapon => {
const player1 = weapon;
const player2 = cpuWeapon[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
getScore(player1, player2)
};

const getScore = (pl1, pl2) => {
if (pl1 === "paper") {
  if (pl2 === "scissor") {
    setPlayerTwo(playerTwo+1)
  } else if (pl2 === "rock") {
     setPlayerOne(playerOne+1)
  }
  }
};
}
```